# Algebraic deformation retract of subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a complex projective variety. Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be two closed subvarieties of $X$. We say $V_2$ admits an algebraic deformation retract to $V_1$ in $X$, if the closed immersion $V_1\hookrightarrow X$ can be deformed along algebraic morphisms to a morphism from $V_1$ to $X$ such that its image is the variety $V_2$. This is equivalent to saying that consider the connected component of the Hom scheme $\text{Hom}(V_1, X)$ such that contains the closed immersion $V_1\hookrightarrow X$. There is another morphism in this connected component such that its image is $V_2$. We define the following relation $R$, we say that for two subvarieties $V_3$ and $V_4$ of $X$, $V_3\text{ } R\text{ } V_4$ when there is a chain of subvarieties from $V_3$ to $V_4$ which each chain is an algebraic deformation retract.

$\textbf{Question1:}$ Is there any hope that one can understand all subvarieties $W$ such that for some fixed subvariety $V$ we have $V\text{ }R\text{ }W$?

$\textbf{Question2:}$ Is it possible to figure out for which low dimensional subvarieties $V$ of $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{P}^d)$, $V$ is related by the $R$ relation to a subvariety of $\text{Sym}^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^d)$? (You need to fix an embedding of $\text{Sym}^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^d)$ into $\text{Sym}^{n}(\mathbb{P}^d)$ which given by adding some fixed point of the projective space.)